# Android button click show different Toast message depend on the click count

Tags: java, android, xamarin, toast

I want to have a button which can show a different toast message depend on the user's click times. The code I write as below. However, after I click, all four toast message pop up. Can anyone help me fix this? THX!

```
GetVS.Click += delegate {

            if(count==0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop0", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            }
            if(count==1)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop1", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            }
            if(count==2)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop2", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop else", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            }

                count++;
        };
```

Comment: Where is `count` defined or initialized?

Comment: Outside the Click function and `private int count =0;`

Comment: You should use `else if` for the 2nd and 3rd `if`s. It will run faster that way.

Comment: You mean if user click the button for too long it will actually keep running many times the click function?

Comment: No. I mean that even if `count==0`, if has to check ALL the other `if`s, even though you know they won't be true, since `count` is `0`, it won't be `1` or `2`.

Comment: Code is not quite correct, I agree. But, eventually, after 3 clicks, it will show a lot of "Beep Boop else" with count>2

Answer (score 1):

`Toast.makeText(..)`  returns a new Instance of Toast, you can create one outside the delegate and then call `myToast.setText` to change the text and then call `Show` to display it.

You are creating 4 instance using `Toast.makeText(..)`, and not changing the text.